Creating groups from dataset based on time intervals
I am working on expanding a script I have made to do some reporting for one of our projects. I need to determine length of video, location and a few other attributes. This part works well when there is 1 video recorded in a log. However, sometimes there can be 2 + recordings inside a single log.
Right now I am thinking it would work best off of the time field, which is in milliseconds.
I have put a very small subset in the image below, some of the logs can be 10,000 rows long.
Basically I am wondering how I would go about creating multiple groups based on if the video is recording (Video On = 1). Below would be two groups (900 to 1400ms and 2200 to 3000ms).
Even some tips on what to look into would be greatly appreciated.


m = df['Video On'] ; df.loc[m, 'time'].groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).agg(['min', 'max'])
